# Change the array of a UITableView

Tags: uitableview, ios6

I´m using a table view to display different types of items. The view controller for the table is always the same, ItemsViewController.

I have a menu with buttons for each type of item. Depending on what button the user clicks, a specific array of items must be used to populate the table view.

My solution:
Every item has an typeId property. When a type button is clicked, the following method is called:

```
    [self.itemController createItemListForId:buttonPressed.typeId];
```

where **buttonPressed** is, well, the pressed menu button.

This is the implementation for createItemListForId:

```
 -(void)createItemListForId:(int)theId{
    for (Item *item in self.masterItemList){
        if(item.typeId == theId){
            [self.itemList addObject:item];
        }
    }
}
```

The **masterItemList** is popluted with all the items at initialization. 
**My ItemsViewController uses the itemList to populate the cells.**

The problem is that itemList is empty when the table view appears, so something not working with this method.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: Try an NSLog on theId is an int being passed in as expected?

Comment: Is the list mutable?  I sometimes had problems when the list wasn't already initialised...